# Wikipedia lens not working

Tags: 12.04

Hey guys I installed a Wikipedia lens a while back and it worked great, but recently ive used it and it dosent work anymore. I open the lens and its just a blank screen im using ubuntu 12.04 ive tried re-installing and installing but no change, any ideas how to fix it please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a Wikipedia-Lens I use the DuckDuckGo-Lens. 
Works pretty much the same.. 
First results are always Wikipedia Results and in case there are no Wikipedia Results use the DuckDuckGo !Bang:

> wiki! or !wiki